# Where clause where record might not exist

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of People with a left join on Cities and I only want to include People in Large cities.  Also include people with no City record

```sql
Select * from People p
left join cities c on c.CityID = p.PCityID
where
c.Size='Large' **or c doesn't exist**
```

I tried:

```sql
Select * from People p
left join cities c on c.CityID = p.PCityID
where
c.Size='Large'
```

This doesn't work because I think it's because it's having trouble with checking c.Size when there's no c record.

Also, this doesn't work because it won't exclude any people since it's a left join:

```
Select * from People p
left join cities c on c.CityID = p.PCityID and c.Size='Large'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if the value of `CityID` is `NULL`:

```sql
SELECT <Explicit List of Columns>
FROM dbo.People P
     LEFT JOIN dbo.Cities C ON P.PCityID = C.CityID
WHERE C.Size = 'Large'
   OR C.CityID IS NULL;
```

This will return rows where the value of `Size` is `'Large'` or where no row in the table `Cities` were found.

Comment: `NOT EXISTS` is a bit more idiomatic

Comment: My thoughts are that the OP wants data from the `Cities` table, @Charlieface , (they did use `SELECT *` after all) and an `EXISTS` doesn't help with that. *If* they don't need data from `Cities`, then an `EXISTS` would likely be preferable.

Comment: True good point, but I feel people often jump to `left join ... is null` unnecessarily, it is usually less efficient

Comment: Well, at least the OP has both solutions depending on their need, @Charlieface . It would be better, however, if sample data and expected results were provided.

Answer (score 1):

You need to rethink you requirement. It can be flipped round as follows:

What you are *actually* trying to say is that you want all `People` that do *not* have a `Cities` which is *not* `'Large'`. So use a `NOT EXISTS` instead

```sql
SELECT
  SpecifyColumnsHere
FROM dbo.People P
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM dbo.Cities C
    WHERE P.PCityID = C.CityID
      AND C.Size <> 'Large'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid using `or` and use `isNull` instead.

```
Select 
*
from People p
left join cities c 
on c.CityID = p.PCityID
where
isNull(c.Size,'') in ('Large','')
```

Answer (score -2):

The chosen method depends on the table space and the index of your table.you can use  ways

1.left join 2.in 3.exists 4.etc

Way 1(with OUTER APPLY ):

```
SELECT  *
FROM People AS p
OUTER APPLY 
(
 SELECT c.CityID,Size
   FROM cities c
   WHERE c.CityID = p.PCityID    
) AS h
WHERE h.CityID IS NULL or h.Size='Large';
```

Way 2(with Left join):

```
Select * from People p
left join cities c on c.CityID = p.PCityID
where c.Size='Large' or c.CityID is null
```

Way 3(with in):

```
Select * from People p
where PCityID  in(select CityID from cities c where c.Size='Large')
or  PCityID not in(select CityID from cities )
```

fiddle:https://dbfiddle.uk/ppt68wdH

performance_comparison–IN vs EXISTS vs LEFTJOIN:
[Link_1](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join)
[Link2](https://www.sqlshack.com/t-sql-commands-performance-comparison-not-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-vs-except/)

Comment: I completed my code and added new way(OUTER APPLY ) and link compare ways